# Executing Celery tasks with Flask application factory

Tags: flask, celery, celery-task

I want to run Celery tasks and clean my database periodicaly.
 For that purpose I have created celery_tasks.py file, which i import into flask application factory  accordingly

```
def create_app():
    load_dotenv('.flaskenv')
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0], instance_relative_config=True)
    env = os.environ.get('FLASK_CONFIG')
    app.config.from_object(config[env])
    ...
    #Celery 
    from api.celery_tasks import make_celery
    make_celery(app)
    ....
    
    return app
```

The **celery_tasks.py** file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from api.database import db_session
from api.models import Account
from sqlalchemy import select
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app):
    celery_instance = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker=app.config['BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery_instance.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery_instance.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
    celery_instance.Task = ContextTask
    
    celery_instance.conf.beat_schedule = {
        'delete_inactive_accounts': {
            'task': 'celery_tasks.delete_inactive_accounts',
            'schedule': timedelta(hours=24),  # Run every 24 hours
        },
        'print_hello': {
            'task': 'celery_tasks.print_hello',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        },
    }
    
    return celery_instance

@Celery.task
def delete_inactive_accounts():
    with db_session():
        threshold_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1)
        inactive_accounts = db_session.scalars(select(Account).where(Account.active < threshold_time)).all()
        for account in inactive_accounts:
            db_session.delete(account)
        db_session.commit()

@Celery.task
def print_hello():
    print("Well well well")
```

After i run flask project with **flask run** everything works fine except the fact that Celery tasks are not executed.
Kindly, advice what am I doing wrong and how can I run Celery tasks with Flask?